# Updating props in Higher Order Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

I'm trying to toggle a radio button and update a prop to what current value it's set on.

My `Modal` component is rendering a `RadioButton` component as so:

```
<RadioButton
  currentValue={destination}
  name={text.newOpp}
  onChange={onClick}
  value={text.newOpp}
  labelText={text.newOpp}
/>
```

The `onClick` function is being passed in and looks like this at the moment:

```
export const onClick = ({ destination }) => ({ target }) => {
  let copyDestination = {};
  copyDestination.destination = target.name;
  destination = copyDestination;
  // this doesn't really do anything
};

export default compose(
  ...
  ...
  withProps({ destination: '' }),
  ...
);
```

`RadioButton` is enhanced with `recompose` and passed this function in as a prop:

```
export const checked = ({ currentValue, value }) => {
  return currentValue === value;
};
```

And this is what the input section of the component looks like:

```
    <input
      checked={checked}
      className={styles.input}
      id={uniqueIdForHTML}
      name={name}
      onChange={onChange}
      type="radio"
      value={value}
    />
```

Essentially, the way this should work is that when I click on a radio button, I update its `currentValue` prop to whatever `target.name` is equal to. But I'm not entirely sure how to update the prop since they should not be altered directly.

Comment: Why you using recompose when there are hooks? Are you just trying to update props of HOC?

Comment: I'm abiding to the coding standards from this project. It's about a year old so everything's built with recompose.

Comment: `currentValue` prop gets value from `destination` - update the `destination` - probably by `setState` in the parent/component that renders `<RadioButton/>` - read docs about `'lifting state up'

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `withStateHandler` to create a state and update it, I also changed the name of my `onClick` function to `setDestination` so it makes more sense.

```
export const setDestination = ({ destination }) => ({ target }) => ({
  destination: target.name,
});

export default compose(
  setDisplayName('OpportunityPageFeatures/CopyDestinationModal'),
  withUniqueIDForHTML,
  withStateHandlers({ destination: '' }, { setDestination }),
  consoleLogProps,
);
```